# The particles that are emitted from my object are all over the place

Tags: particles, collections

So I'm trying to have grass grow from a rock. I have a collection with two different patches of grass that I am using to cover my rock. Although, when I created my particle system, the patches of grass are being emitted in some really bizarre ways.

Sometimes they are protruding from the side, the bottom, or even near the top (making the bottom part stick partially out). If you look inside the model, this can easily be seem. The majority of my grass patches are awkwardly protruding out of the rock from the side.

I'm having trouble solving this problem and was wondering if anyone knows how to make it so that the patched of grass protrude from the bottom???

[Here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah2aL3r7RO3ThJJAAGtoLcnW4ZPBdg?e=ujwdiG) is a link in case anyone wants to take a peek at my file, and down below are a few screen shots.

[image]

[image]

[image]